# Как сделать слайдер для такой галереи?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется галерея [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такой слайдер, чтобы он принимал данные маленких изображений и соответственно при смене главного слайда маленькое изображение получало активный класс?

Картинки беру из backgound-image
вот js код

```
var $galleryItem = $('.gallery_item');
    var $galleryMain = $('.gallery_main');
    $galleryItem.click(changePhoto);
    function changePhoto() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newImage = $this.css('backgroundImage');
        $galleryMain.css('backgroundImage', newImage);
        $galleryItem.removeClass('gallery_active');
        $this.addClass('gallery_active');
    }
```

Спасибо!

Comment: дак при нажатии на стрелку надо найти активный элемент, с него класс убрать, к следующему добавить. В общем то нужен всего один метод смены, куда будет передаваться, например, индекс новой картинки. Этот метод вызывать и при клике на миниатюру и на стрелки. зы: обычно миниатюры физически делают маленького размера, чтобы не гонять траффик зы2: возьмите готовые решения для галерей, нет особого смысла городить велосипеды и создавать свое.

Comment: [Slider Syncing -- найди на странице](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: Спасибо! Тогда ищу готовые решения.